# How to check orientdb disk cache size at runtime?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I'm trying to tune an orientdb 2.1.5 embedded application, reducing at the minimum the I/O to disk.
I've read the documentation (http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Performance-Tuning.html) and used the **storage.diskCache.bufferSize** flag to increment the disk cache size.
Looking at htop and top (I'm on linux) I've not noticed any increment in java process's memory usage though. Even the two mbeans exposed by orient (**O2QCacheMXBean** and **OWOWCacheMXBean**) don't highlight evidence about the increment. So how can I be sure of the current disk cache size?

This is part of my java command line:

```
java -server -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.20.154 -Dstorage.useWAL=false -Dstorage.wal.syncOnPageFlush=false -Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=16384 -Dtx.useLog=false -Xms4g -Xmx4g -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:/home/nexse/local/gc.log -jar my.jar
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: **Update** after some dubugging I've found this really useful flag: environment.dumpCfgAtStartup